# What does "Cannot write to closing transport" mean?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I get the exception `"Cannot write to closing transport"` raised from `aiohttp.http_writer.StreamWriter#_write`, but only  in a fraction of cases.

The relevant snippet.

```
    session: aiohttp.ClientSession
    async with session.get(url, timeout=60) as response:
        txt = await response.text()
        response.close()
        return txt
```

What is going on? I don't think the server-size is closing the socket.

Comment: How is that possible? In this code, we  await response.text(). So if we got to response.close(), the full HTTP response is finished, right?

Comment: You can reproduce this:
add asyncio.sleep(10) to you handler, call it and stop waiting (break connection from client side) before it respond you. You will see same error in server logs

Comment: I think when you closing connection server still responding smth. Why do you closing connection (response.close()) manually? AFAIK connection will close automatically when `__aexit__()` of ClientSessionContextManager will be called.

Comment: Smal remark: `_SessionRequestContextManager` not `ClientSessionContextManager`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer: We should  create a new session on each request. There is also no need to close the `response()` explicitly, as the context manager handles that.

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession().get(url, timeout=60) as response:
    txt = await response.text()
    return txt
```

Comment: Dedicated session for each request is what helped me fix the `Cannot write to closing transport` exception, although the documentation of `aiohttp` says the opposite: `Create the session first, use the instance for performing HTTP requests and initiating WebSocket connections.` (https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/v3.0.1/client_advanced.html#client-session). I'm using `aiohttp` 3.6.2 (2019-10-09) and Python 3.6.9 on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 3):

It means that your connection already closed. It occurs when client break connection, but server still tried respond him.

Remove `response.close()` from your code.

Comment: How is that possible that the HTTP response is continuing, given that response.text() has consumed all the response?

Comment: @JoshuaFox It occurs because you close connection manually (`response.close()`). Don't do this. It will be closed automatically when you get out from `_SessionRequestContextManager`

Comment: OK, that makes sense

Comment: The mistake is simply that I use response.close(). If I omit response.close(), the session context-manager closes the response by itself.

Comment: I don't use response close. But I get this error when the client disconnects sometimes. How can I handle it? Try catch on websocket emit doesnt work.

Comment: @TheFool AFAIK you can't catch this.

Comment: @TheFool or try to wrap your `cs.request` context manager with `try ... catch`

Answer (score 0):

This happens if a client prematurely disconnects before reading some or all of the response. You may encounter that case frequently if you're either dealing with mobile clients (which may switch between WiFi and mobile networks) or if you have views that take some time, but clients have a lower timeout. Since you can't control how clients talk to your service, it's probably safe to ignore this.

> aiohttp 3.6.0 [introduces code](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3648) to slience this exception